# Display all available java versions on machine

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I'm writing an eclipse plug-in and I need to display all versions of Java installed on users machine. I know about this code:

```
String javaVersion = System.getProperty("java.version");
```

but it only returns currently selected Java version. How would I get them all?

Comment: Running ou Windows or Linux?

Comment: There's no easy way for that. A java runtime environment might be located anywhere on the user's machine (or even network drives...). You basically need to find a ``java`` binary, call ``java --version`` and parse the output.

Comment: I'm using Linux, CentOS 6 to be precise.

Comment: The better question is, how will you know where they're installed? You can look in common places, but there's no guarantee you'll find every version unless you search the entire drive.

Comment: Eclipse keeps track of the installed Java versions. Have a look at Preferences/Java/Installed JREs. But the user is responsible to add alternative JREs himself to this list. I think it should be possible to query the entries of this list. If it were easy to programmatically find all installed runtimes, I guess the eclipse folks would already have done this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function will search for given version of Java and in case it doesn't find it, it will return null.

```
public static IClasspathEntry getJavaClassPath(String version) {
    IExecutionEnvironmentsManager executionEnvironmentsManager = JavaRuntime
            .getExecutionEnvironmentsManager();
    IExecutionEnvironment[] executionEnvironments = executionEnvironmentsManager
            .getExecutionEnvironments();
    for (IExecutionEnvironment iExecutionEnvironment : executionEnvironments) {
        if (version.equals(iExecutionEnvironment.getId())) {
            return JavaCore.newContainerEntry(JavaRuntime
                    .newJREContainerPath(iExecutionEnvironment));
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

And then just check if versions you want exist:

```
private String[] getAvailableJavaVersions() {
    List<String> userJavaVersions = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(String javaVersion: Arrays.asList("1.6", "1.7", "1.8")) {
        if(MaxJProject.getJavaClassPath("JavaSE-" + javaVersion) != null) {
            userJavaVersions.add(javaVersion);
        }
    }

    return userJavaVersions.toArray(new String[userJavaVersions.size()]);
}
```

The only problem with this is that the list of versions is predetermined.

Answer (score 1):

This is much more complicated then you think.

Of course, when you run some java class; that already runs inside a **single** JVM. And that JVM installation doesn't have *any* idea if/where *other* JVMs might exist on your system.

Therefore it depends on your operating system where other JVMs might be located.

On a Linux system, you could go for

> find / -name "java" -type f 2>/dev/null

On my system, that creates output like:

```
/usr/lib/j2re1.7-ibm/jre/bin/java
/usr/lib/j2sdk1.7-ibm/jre/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-ibm-x86_64-80/jre/bin/java
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/java
/data/home/Downloads/ibm-java-x86_64-80/jre/bin/java
...
```

That is the whole point: a user can place JVM binaries all over his file system. And he could be starting a JVM within all those different directories.

So the real answer here: step back; and look at the requirement behind your question. Why do you think you need to know about this? And from there: how can you get rid of the requirement?

Answer (score 1):

You wrote that you are using Linux, but I add this answer for someone who looks for the Mac OSX solution:

```
 /usr/libexec/java_home -V
Matching Java Virtual Machines (12):
1.8.0_131, x86_64:  "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home
1.8.0_121, x86_64:  "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home
1.8.0_112, x86_64:  "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_112.jdk/Contents/Home
1.8.0_102, x86_64:  "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_102.jdk/Contents/Home
1.8.0_92, x86_64:   "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/Home
1.8.0_77, x86_64:   "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_77.jdk/Contents/Home
1.8.0_74, x86_64:   "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home
1.8.0_72, x86_64:   "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_72.jdk/Contents/Home
1.8.0_66, x86_64:   "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_66.jdk/Contents/Home
1.8.0_65, x86_64:   "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home
1.8.0_60, x86_64:   "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home
1.7.0_80, x86_64:   "Java SE 7" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home
```

assuming that the Oracle Java versions are installed.